# Android - Click sound onClick of a button stops after rapidly clicking

Tags: android, audio

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581844/button-click-sound-mediaplayer-crashes-if-buttons-are-pressed-too-rapidly) post, however nothing is working. Here's my current code:

```
private static MediaPlayer mp;
public void onClick(View v) {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.reset();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        afd = getAssets().openFd("click.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    increment(button, key, this);
}
```

When I rapidly click on the button, the sound stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, you just have to add:

```
if(mediaPlayer == null)
```

before you create a new `MediaPlayer`. So, in your case:

```
if(mediaPlayer == null)
   mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

And make sure `mediaPlayer` is a global variable.

Comment: And second option is disable click button. But it is not correct way

Comment: I get the warning "boolean `mp==null` is always `false`". Is this true?

Comment: please declare mp is global variable

Comment: `mp` is a global variable now, but it still doesn't work even with your solution.

Comment: This answer is long and not helpful for future visitors; I have suggested an edit to the answer making it more clear :)

Comment: Ok fine bro..i approved your answer